# Amazon MWS SubmitFeed Updating stock quantity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm having problems with a stock quantity update feed using Amazon MWS. My Feed is submitted and processed, but I get errors, however if I submit the same XML via the scratchpad, the inventory updates are accepted and processed.

(merchant id starred out deliberately)

Submission and response below:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>************</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Inventory>
        <SKU>BUS999904</SKU>
        <Quantity>269</Quantity>
    </Inventory>
</Message>
<Message>
    <MessageID>2</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Inventory>
        <SKU>PROBS-HO-01</SKU>
        <Quantity>137</Quantity>
    </Inventory>
</Message>
```

And the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_ONTRACKSCO_1106147</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <ProcessingReport>
        <DocumentTransactionID>54774016520</DocumentTransactionID>
        <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
        <ProcessingSummary>
            <MessagesProcessed>2</MessagesProcessed>
            <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
            <MessagesWithError>2</MessagesWithError>
            <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
        </ProcessingSummary>
        <Result>
            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
            <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
            <ResultMessageCode>25</ResultMessageCode>
            <ResultDescription>We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.  </ResultDescription>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <MessageID>2</MessageID>
            <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
            <ResultMessageCode>25</ResultMessageCode>
            <ResultDescription>We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.</ResultDescription>
        </Result>
    </ProcessingReport>
</Message>
```

Any help anyone can give, or pointers/examples of valid stock update feeds would be most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I finally worked it out - I had the incorrect feed type in my post. It should have been set to _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML seems to be missing `</AmazonEnvelope>` at the end of the feed, but that could easily be an error in pasting it here. Once I added that, I was able to validate your XML against my copy of the XSDs. Other than that, my inventory feed only differs in one way: I have an additional `<FulfillmentLatency>1</FulfillmentLatency>` following right after each `Quanitity`, which is not mandatory according to the XSDs.

Comment: Hi Hazzit - thanks for your response. You are correct, the closing </AmazonEnvelope> was missing due to a pasting error. I tried adding the additional field for each item, but no joy. Still getting the same error code 25. It's back to trawling through the XSDs with a fine tooth comb for me....

Answer (score 0):

Amazon MWS Update Inventory Stock Sample Code:

```
<?php
/**********************************************************
* Update inventory stock through amazon mws api
*
***********************************************************/

$sku1        = '10101-AM';
$quantity1   = '9';
$leadTimeToShip1 = '7';

//amazon mws credentials
$amazonSellerId         = 'xxxxxx';
$amazonMWSAuthToken     = 'xxxxxx';
$amazonAWSAccessKeyId   = 'xxxxxx';
$amazonSecretKey        = 'xxxxxx';
$amazonMarketPlaceId    = 'xxxxxx';

$param = array();
$param['AWSAccessKeyId']     = $amazonAWSAccessKeyId;
$param['Action']             = 'SubmitFeed'; 
$param['Merchant']           = $amazonSellerId;
$param['MWSAuthToken']       = $amazonMWSAuthToken; 
$param['FeedType']       = '_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_';
$param['SignatureMethod']    = 'HmacSHA256';  
$param['SignatureVersion']   = '2'; 
$param['Timestamp']          = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
$param['Version']            = '2009-01-01'; 
$param['MarketplaceIdList.Id.1'] = $amazonMarketPlaceId;
$param['PurgeAndReplace']    = 'false';

$secret = $amazonSecretKey;

$url = array();
foreach ($param as $key => $val) {

    $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
    $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));
    $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
}

$amazon_feed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>'.$amazonSellerId.'</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
    <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Inventory>
    <SKU>'.$sku1.'</SKU>
    <Quantity>'.$quantity1.'</Quantity>
    <FulfillmentLatency>'.$leadTimeToShip1.'</FulfillmentLatency>
    </Inventory>
    </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>';

//echo $amazon_feed;exit;
sort($url);

$arr   = implode('&', $url);

$sign  = 'POST' . "\n";
$sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.com' . "\n";
$sign .= '/Feeds/'.$param['Version'].'' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;

$signature      = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, $secret, true);
$httpHeader     =   array();
$httpHeader[]   =   'Transfer-Encoding: chunked';
$httpHeader[]   =   'Content-Type: application/xml';
$httpHeader[]   =   'Content-MD5: ' . base64_encode(md5($amazon_feed, true));
//$httpHeader[]   =   'x-amazon-user-agent: MyScriptName/1.0';
$httpHeader[]   =   'Expect:';
$httpHeader[]   =   'Accept:';              

$signature      = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$link  = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Feeds/".$param['Version']."?";
$link .= $arr . "&Signature=" . $signature;


$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $amazon_feed); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$errors=curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response); //xml response


?>
```